# How to make an object public?

Tags: php

how would I go about getting around the "protected" so I can output the data.

```
tabs\api\property\Property Object ( 
    [id:protected] => 90_4_HH 
    [propertyRef:protected] => 90_4 
    [brandCode:protected] => HH 
    [url:protected] => http://hh.api.carltonsoftware.co.uk/property/90_4_HH
    [accountingBrand:protected] => HH 
    [slug:protected] => 90-4-hh 
    [name:protected] => Carreg Lwyd Farmhouse 
    [address:protected] => tabs\api\core\Address Object ( 
        [addr1:protected] => Port Eynon 
        [addr2:protected] => 
        [town:protected] => Gower 
        [county:protected] => Swansea 
        [postcode:protected] => SA3 1NN 
        [country:protected] => GB 
    ) 
    [changeOverDay:protected] => Saturday 
    [calendar:protected] => http://hh.api.carltonsoftware.co.uk/property/90_4_HH/calendar 
    [booking:protected] => http://hh.api.carltonsoftware.co.uk/booking 
    [pets:protected] => 
    [promote:protected] => 
    [smoking:protected] => 
    [shortlist:protected] => 
    [accommodates:protected] => 12 
    [rating:protected] => 5 
    [bedrooms:protected] => 6 
    [images:protected] => Array ( 
        [90_4p1190276.jpg?APIKEY=homefromhome&hash=31b3f7b1b377184e8cb8fb64d434a11a4c3446c1091535ef6db4e119689a6372] => tabs\api\property\Image Object ( 
            [filename:protected] => 90_4p1190276.jpg?APIKEY=homefromhome&hash=31b3f7b1b377184e8cb8fb64d434a11a4c3446c1091535ef6db4e119689a6372 
            [title:protected] => Carreg Lwyd Farmhouse, Port Eynon 
            [alt:protected] => The Lounge 
            [url:protected] => http://hh.api.carltonsoftware.co.uk/image/normal/1000x750/90_4p1190276.jpg 
            [height:protected] => 750 
            [width:protected] => 1000 
            [apiPath:protected] => http://hh.api.carltonsoftware.co.uk 
        ) 
        [90_4img_4819.jpg?APIKEY=homefromhome&hash=31b3f7b1b377184e8cb8fb64d434a11a4c3446c1091535ef6db4e119689a6372] => tabs\api\property\Image Object (
```

The dump:

```
foreach ($properties as $property) {
echo sprintf('<p class="listit">%s</p>', $property);
print_r($property);
}
```

Comment: You look at the methods that are available to your Property object

Comment: How would I go about doing this. I'm new to this kind of thing.

Comment: You are likely looking for get methods,  you might also implement __toString() or something like getData() as a method inside the class and have it return the data representation that you want as you can access all of those protected properties from inside the instance.

Comment: Could you provide an example please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not fully understand your question, but if you want to access *protected* properties from outside the class, you have to use Reflection:

```
$reflObj = new ReflectionObject($property);
$props = $reflObj->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED);

foreach ($props as $prop) {
  $prop->setAccessible(true);
  echo $prop->getName() . ":" . $prop->getValue($property), "\n";
}
```

Sample for outputting the address:

```
$reflObj = new ReflectionObject($property);
$addrProp = $reflObj->getProperty('address');

$addrProp->setAccessible(true);
echo $addrProp->getValue($property);
```

Comment: Cannot access non-public member tabs\api\property\Property::id

Comment: @Alex Is this an error message? In which line did you get it? Please try the **updated** script.

Comment: That's the message that's thrown out yes, I attempted the update and same result :/

Comment: @Alex I'm sorry for the inconvenience, I forgot a method call. It should definitely work now (I tested it).

Comment: Where does `$property` come from? `$prop->getValue($property)`

Comment: @TobiasKun It is his `$property` object (see his dump in the question). The names are a bit confusable in this case.

Comment: Getting an ouput, any way of being more precise. For example, simply echoing a description, name etc?

Comment: @Alex What description?! My code outpus the property's name and its value. There is no more information stored anywhere.

Comment: For example, echoing the address, I'm just looking for some more reference points.

Comment: At the moment I'm getting "id:96B_HH propertyRef:96B brandCode:HH url:http://hh.api.carltonsoftware.co.uk/property/96B_HH accountingBrand:HH slug:96b-hh name:The Farmhouse address:Fairfield Farm, Knelston, Reynoldston, Gower, Swansea, SA3 1AR, GB changeOverDay:Saturday calendar:http://hh.api.carltonsoftware.co.uk/property/96B_HH/calendar booking:http://hh.api.carltonsoftware.co.uk/booking pets:1 promote: smoking: shortlist: accommodates:8 rating:3 bedrooms:4 images:Array brands:Array attributes:Array coordinates:51.578166,-4.214107 availability:Array specialOffers:Array "

Comment: We know Alex. Start looking at the classes. For example: `tabs\api\core\Address`. Do you can access the code? Look for getters and setters.

Comment: @Alex So you already get the address in the output (as posted in your comment)? Where's the problem, now? Do you know how to get a single property? Please read the documentation.

Comment: I just wanted to know if I can grab a specific property from the string.

Comment: The help has been great by the way, I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your title implies that you want to make -the class (not object)- public, as opposed to "internal"/etc.. All classes are public in PHP.

Your question says that you want to get around method/property scope (disagrees with title). You didn't say what you've tried. You also didn't indicate whether this is a class you developed or not. If you have control over it, add a freaking method or two to allow you to get the data. If you don't, then inspect the methods, and/or attempt reflection. These answers apply to every OOP language in existence.

Before asking other people, read the documentation.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question posed by the title is that all classes are public.

What you are asking is how to access protected member variables.

Taken from here (http://ajmm.org/2011/06/using-php-reflection-to-read-a-protected-property/), this is an example of how to do this:

```
public static function getReflectedPropertyValue($class, $propertyName)
{
    $reflectedClass = new ReflectionClass($class);
    $property = $reflectedClass->getProperty($propertyName);
    $property->setAccessible(true);

    return $property->getValue($class);
}

...

getReflectedPropertyValue($yourObject, 'protectedProperty');
```

That said, the question is why you want to do this.  Members are marked protected specifically to prevent you from doing this.  If you have access to the source code that defines this other class, then it might make more sense to either change these members to "public" or (better) to provide a getXYZ() method for whichever properties you want to access.